# Can VideoANT be used to annotate private YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube, video

There's a web app at https://ant.umn.edu/ which lets you annotate videos; now is it possible to use VideoANT to have multiple people annotate the videos, and keep the videos shared with just the selected people while it is being produced?

There are [two settings in YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poGiVTXuqS8), one is unlisted, and the other is private; unlisted leaves the videos out there, and private makes it so that you need to have someone's email address listed to view it.

Comment: Looks like there is an answer here: https://ant.umn.edu/documentation##section-private-youtube-uploads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems OP was happy with the information he found at [College of Education + Human Development](https://ant.umn.edu/documentation##section-private-youtube-uploads):

> **Private YouTube Uploads**
>
> When creating an Ant, you will find it easiest to add YouTube videos
>   with the “Unlisted” privacy setting.
>
> 1. Open two tabs in the same browser. Sign in to VideoAnt in one tab and your YouTube account in the other. Note: This should be the YouTube account that includes the private video you would like to annotate.
> 2. In the YouTube tab, navigate to the private video and copy the share URL.
> 3. In the VideoAnt tab select “New Ant,” paste the URL, and select “Load.”
> 4. To share the Ant of this private YouTube video you will, first, need to give them access to your private video in YouTube and then share the Ant with the same email address.

Comment: Op: Yep, that's what happened.